# How to check Current SDK version of Google AdMob iOS?

Tags: objective-c, admob

Google has Changed some Policy under which the ads displayed under SDK version 7.0 will not display ads any more, Actually i don't know which version SDK i m using.

Please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**pragma mark GADRequest implementation**

```
- (GADRequest *)request {
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];


NSLog(@"Received ad successfully %@ " , [GADRequest sdkVersion] );

request.testDevices = @[
                        kGADSimulatorID
                        ];
return request;
}
```

Implement the above code in your iOS Project
And Check Log

you will get Output something like this

> afma-sdk-i-v7.27.0

Answer (score 9):

**SWIFT:**

```
print(GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().sdkVersion)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    NSLog(@"admob version  %@ " ,[[GADMobileAds sharedInstance] sdkVersion]);
```

Comment: Please remember to include an explanation of your code, instead of just answering with code. Can you edit your answer to include that? In particular, it may be useful to explain why you prefer `GADMobileAds` over `GADRequest`, as proposed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Google Mobile Ads SDK version 11.0.0 `sdkVersion` has been removed from `GADMobileAds`.
[Changes to logging SDK version](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/migration#changes_to_logging_sdk_version)

Now you have to use `versionNumber` that returns `GADVersionNumber`. If you want to have the string representation of the version number then do this instead:

Swift:

```swift
GADGetStringFromVersionNumber(GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().versionNumber)
```

Objective-C:

```
GADGetStringFromVersionNumber([[GADMobileAds sharedInstance] versionNumber]);
```