# How to know google SDK version ios?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sdk, admob, version

Google has changed policy under which the ads will not display in SDK under version 7.0 any more. How to get SDK version of google admob?

Comment: [Please Check this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203987/how-to-check-current-sdk-version-of-google-admob-ios/48204094#48204094) this will Solve your Problem

Comment: thank you saved my time.